# Trying to Connect Search Feature to Textbox In Vb.net

Tags: sql, database, vb.net

I am struggling to link my search code to a text box in order to actually search and type in possible searches. How do I connect my Text box to my search code to make it work?

(a little context, I am trying to connect a SQL database in visual basic (vb.net) and to have a searchable database or spreadsheet)

I tried putting the code within the text box sub below. Anything Helps!

```
Private Sub TextBox1_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles TextBox1.TextChanged
    Try

        Using connection = New SqlConnection("Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=vbconnectionfinal;Integrated Security=True")
            ' create a new instance of the command object
            Using Command = New SqlCommand("Select * From TrueTrack WHERE UserName = @name AND DeviceType = @type", connection)

                ' parameterize the query
                Command.Parameters.Add("@name", SqlDbType.VarChar, 100).Value = "my name search"
                Command.Parameters.Add("@type", SqlDbType.VarChar, 100).Value = "my device type search"

                ' create a new instance of the data adapter object
                Using adapter = New SqlDataAdapter(Command)
                    ' fill a DataTable with the data from the adapter
                    Dim table = New DataTable()
                    adapter.Fill(table)
                    DataGridView1.DataSource = Table

                End Using
            End Using
        End Using
    Catch ex As Exception

        ' display the error
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)

    End Try
End Sub
```

Comment: Consider also that making search on the database in the TextChanged event is not very wise. A fast typing user could trigger a lot of TextChanged events and each one will search just a part of the final text and you need to wait the end of the call before starting immediately another one. That's why many apps add a button that the user has to click to start the search.

Comment: On another note, what do you do with that table filled with the dataadapter?. This code seems to do nothing with it and none will be able to see the result of your search

Comment: I was missing a line, DataGridView1.DataSource = Table, that I think solves your second comment, and thanks I will add a search button instead of a straight search. Thanks Steve

Comment: @PasskyyCode then update the code in your question to include the missing line

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One method of querying based on TextBox values is using a timer which only runs after some amount of time after a final keypress. This example will query after 1 second elapses after the last change to the TextBox. It also off-loads the query from the UI thread onto the timer thread, which is a background thread. So your UI won't freeze while running the query

```vb
Private ReadOnly queryTimer As New System.Threading.Timer(AddressOf runQuery, Nothing, -1, -1)
Private queryString As String
Private textChangeQueryDelay As Integer = 1000

Private Sub TextBox1_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles TextBox1.TextChanged
    queryString = TextBox1.Text
    queryTimer.Change(textChangeQueryDelay, -1)
End Sub

Private Sub runQuery(state As Object)
    Dim table = New DataTable()
    Using connection = New SqlConnection("Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=vbconnectionfinal;Integrated Security=True")
        Using Command = New SqlCommand("Select * From TrueTrack WHERE UserName = @name AND DeviceType = @type", connection)
            Command.Parameters.Add("@name", SqlDbType.VarChar, 100).Value = queryString
            Command.Parameters.Add("@type", SqlDbType.VarChar, 100).Value = "my device type search"
            Using adapter = New SqlDataAdapter(Command)
                adapter.Fill(table)
            End Using
        End Using
    End Using
    DataGridView1.Invoke(Sub() DataGridView1.DataSource = table)
End Sub
```

But it's not clear where `"my name search"` and `"my device type search"` come from. I assume the name comes from TextBox1 so that's what the code does.

Another thing is you are checking for equality in your query, but a more appropriate thing (since you were acting on TextChanged) may be to check for like i.e.

```vb
Using Command = New SqlCommand("Select * From TrueTrack WHERE UserName like @name AND DeviceType = @type")
...
Command.Parameters.Add("@name", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 100).Value = "%" & querystring & "%"
```

That way you return all results with name like your TextBox text. This feels more "right" since you were querying as the user typed. But for exact matches, especially with multiple where clauses (I still hadn't reconciled that in this answer), acting once on a Button click as mentioned in comments might be your best bet.

**Update based on comment**

You can query on both name and type by calling the query timer in each of their TextBox_TextChanged event handlers (or make one handler handle both)

```vb
Private ReadOnly queryTimer As New System.Threading.Timer(AddressOf runQuery, Nothing, -1, -1)
Private searchName As String
Private searchType As String
Private textChangeQueryDelay As Integer = 1000

Private Sub TextBoxes_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles TextBox1.TextChanged, TextBox2.TextChanged
    searchName = TextBox1.Text
    searchType = TextBox2.Text
    queryTimer.Change(textChangeQueryDelay, -1)
End Sub
```

and in the query you can conditionally add or not add the parameters

```vb
Private Sub runQuery(state As Object)
    Dim table = New DataTable()
    Using connection = New SqlConnection("Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=vbconnectionfinal;Integrated Security=True")
        Using command = New SqlCommand()
            command.Connection = connection
            Dim commandText = "SELECT * FROM TrueTrack WHERE 1=1 "
            If Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(searchName) Then
                commandText &= " AND UserName like @name "
                command.Parameters.Add("@name", SqlDbType.VarChar, 100).Value = "%" & searchName & "%"
            End If
            If Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(searchType) Then
                commandText &= " AND DeviceType like @type "
                command.Parameters.Add("@type", SqlDbType.VarChar, 100).Value = "%" & searchType & "%"
            End If
            command.CommandText = commandText
            Using adapter = New SqlDataAdapter(command)
                adapter.Fill(table)
            End Using
        End Using
    End Using
    DataGridView1.Invoke(Sub() DataGridView1.DataSource = table)
End Sub
```

Comment: This Helped a ton Thank You! Still having a bit of a problem searching for the DeviceType but UserName search works perfectly.

Comment: @PasskyyCode see my updated answer

Comment: Thank You again, Fixed my issue!!

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't have all that database code run every time a user types a letter into the text box. How about a user clicks a button when they are ready to search.

The `Command` and `connectio`n can be combined in a single `Using` block by adding a comma at the end of the first line.

The values of the command parameters are the parameters you passed to the function.

You don't need the extra overhead of a `DataAdapter`. Just `Load` a `DataTable` with a `DataReader`.

```
Private Function SearchDatabase(Name As String, Type As String) As DataTable
    Dim dt As New DataTable
    Using connection = New SqlConnection("Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=vbconnectionfinal;Integrated Security=True"),
            Command = New SqlCommand("Select * From TrueTrack WHERE UserName = @name AND DeviceType = @type", connection)
        Command.Parameters.Add("@name", SqlDbType.VarChar, 100).Value = Name
        Command.Parameters.Add("@type", SqlDbType.VarChar, 100).Value = Type
        connection.Open()
        Using reader = Command.ExecuteReader
            dt.Load(reader)
        End Using
    End Using
    Return dt
End Function

Private Sub Button1_Click() Handles Button1.Click
    Dim dt As DataTable
    Try
        dt = SearchDatabase(txtName.Text, txtType.Text)
    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
        Exit Sub
    End Try
    'Use the values in the DataTable as needed
End Sub
```

Answer (score -1):

You could make use of a general database manager class that handles parameterization for you

- It will take this DB code out of your form
- Easier to maintain your DB code since it will only be in one place
- All you have to do is instantiate the db manager and pass sql and parameters to it so you don't have to keep repeating your code like this

Here is what a DB manager might look like:

```vb
Imports System.Data.SqlClient

Public Class DBManager
    Public Function GetDataSet(sql As String, Optional parameters As Dictionary(Of String, Object) = Nothing) As DataSet
        Using connection As New SqlConnection("Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=vbconnectionfinal;Integrated Security=True")
            Try
                ' Attempt to establish connection
                If connection.State <> ConnectionState.Open Then
                    connection.Open()
                End If
            
                Using cmd As New SqlCommand(sql, connection)
                    ' Add parameters
                    If parameters IsNot Nothing Then
                        For Each key As String in parameters
                            cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter(key, parameters(key)))
                        Next
                    End If
            
                    ' Fill dataset
                    Dim ds As New DataSet
                    Dim adapter As New SqlDataAdapter(cmd)
                    adapter.Fill(ds)
            
                    ' Return dataset
                    Return ds
                End Using
            Catch ex As Exception
                ' Log to some central manager or file or throw to caller
                ' Throw ex
            End Try
        End Using
        
        Return Nothing
    End Function

    Public Function ExecuteCommand(sql As String, Optional parameters As Dictionary(Of String, Object) = Nothing) As Integer
        Using connection As New SqlConnection("Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=vbconnectionfinal;Integrated Security=True")
            Try 
                ' Attempt to establish connection
                If connection.State <> ConnectionState.Open Then
                    connection.Open()
                End If
        
                Using cmd As New SqlCommand(sql, connection)
                    ' Add parameters
                    If parameters IsNot Nothing Then
                        For Each key As String in parameters
                            cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter(key, parameters(key)))
                        Next
                    End If
            
                    Return cmd.ExecuteNonQuery() ' Count of affected rows
                End Using
            Catch ex As Exception
                ' Log to some central manager or file or throw to caller
                ' Throw ex
            End Try
        End Using
    
        Return -1
    End Function
End Class
```

You could then make use of this manager in various places throughout your code

```vb
Module Module1
    Sub Main()
        ' Sql Only
        Dim conn As New DBManager
        Dim sql As String = "SELECT * FROM TestData;"
        
        Try
            ' Remember parameters are optional
            Dim ds As DataSet = conn.GetDataSet(sql)

            If ds IsNot Nothing Then
                ' Do work on retrieved dataset
            End If
        Catch ex As Exception
            ' Catch here if db manager is throwing
        End Try
    
        ' Parameterized sql
        sql = "INSERT INTO TestData (Value) 
               VALUES (@value);"
        Dim parameters As New Dictionary(Of String, Object) From {
            { "@value", "x" }
        }
    
        Try
            Dim affectedRows As Integer = conn.ExecuteCommand(sql, parameters)

            If affectedRows = -1 Then
                ' Something went wrong
            End If
        Catch ex As Exception
            ' Catch here if db manager is throwing
        End Try
    End Sub
End Module
```

Comment: I did not downvote, but I don't see how this answer attempts to address the original question. It just seems like some helper functions which do the same thing OP was already doing plus a method to insert, which is not even necessary here. Did you not notice that OP was querying data using parameters and the only thing you did which resembles what OP was doing is calling your `GetDataSet`, which you call *without* parameters?

Comment: My reasoning behind this is the various things going wrong in his original post. I already know he was manually adding parameters, however, he doesn’t do anything with the resulting dataset he attaches to the adapter. The intent was to show a pattern that he can use to make his code less confusing and would be less prone to forgetting to use the result. As for the above answer, regardless if I used the dictionary or not, the Optional works the same way for both functions. Was just showing the flexibility to use with or without parameterization. As for your points, I can see why you questioned.

Comment: I didn't downvote either but I will try to add a few improvements. You really haven't decoupled the database code from the user interface if you are writing sql strings and parameters in the ui. You are essentially writing AddWithValue code since you don't supply a datatype for your parameters. There are articles relating to this all over the internet. Why would you check the state of the connection when you just created it on the line above? Don't open the connection until directly before the Execute.

Comment: Why would you need a DataSet? Won't a DataTable do? You wouldn't open a connection for a DataAdapter, the adapter does it for you. Why use a DataAdapter anyway, just Load a DataTable with a DataReader.

Comment: @Mary my goal wasn’t really to abstract his code, it was mainly to get it into one, uniform place to make things a little easier. I typed the solution above on my phone so I’m not sure what I was thinking with checking connection.

Comment: I’d like to use a dataset in case we have more than one select statement in the sql. The adapter would fill one data table in the same set. No point in opening multiple connections if I have to execute multiple select statements in sequence when I can simply get them all at the same time and save on network IO.